# persistent error when starting react native run android

Tags: android, react-native

I installed everything correctly. react native, node js, jdk, android studio and all system variables have been installed. I can create a "react-native init project" project, but when I run it gives this error:

'''Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.'''

I've reinstalled everything and I don't know what else to do ... can someone help me?

Comment: Make sure you're inside of the project folder.

Comment: I think I am.  I created the project "reac-native init project" and then just put it to run.  do you need to do something else?

Comment: You you should go into the project folder with `cd`. The directory path that you see in your bash/cmd must be the project folder. For example: C:/Users/username/Desktop/project

Comment: hello, it's already in the correct directory ... I don't know what else to do :(PS C:\Users\igorr\Desktop\projeto native> react-native run android
Command `run` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
PS C:\Users\igorr\Desktop\projeto native>

Comment: `Command run unrecognized.` this is a different error. it means you're using the command wrong. It must be `react-native run-android` with a dash between run and android

Comment: do you have WhatsApp or any medium that can be more interactive?  so I can send pictures of the terminal and the code